# MediaRecorderObjectのサンプル

Tags: spresense

MediaRecorderObjectを利用したサンプルが公開される予定はありますか？
MediaPlayerObjectに関しては、Arduinoにサンプルがあると思うのですが、
MediaRecorderObjectも同じようにサンプルが公開されるでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ソニーのSPRESENSEサポート担当です。
十分なサンプルが準備できず、誠に申し訳ありません。

最新のライブラリ version 1.1.0 に、MediaRecoderObjectのサンプルコードを追加いたしました。

ライブラリのアップデートは、Arduino IDE の「ボードマネージャ」で行ってください。

アップデート後、Arduino IDE のメニューの

「ファイル」→「スケッチ例」->「Spresense用スケッチ例：Audio」->「application」

を開いていただくと、

recorder_objif
recorder_wav_objif

という2つのサンプルコードが追加されています。
これらが MediaRecorderObject のサンプルになります。

ご利用の際は、お手数ですがブートローダを更新していただく必要があります。
ご注意ください。

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。